# 3D- controller says that the kernel driver is both Nvidia and Nouveau

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

As the title says; here is an extract of what the terminal says after

```
$ lspci -k
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev a2)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau.
```

I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04, my GPU is a GEFORCE 940mx.
This happened after I followed this [guide](https://tutorials.technology/tutorials/85-How-to-remove-Nouveau-kernel-driver-Nvidia-install-error.html).

The tutorial did its job nvidia drivers are now installed but it didn't get rid of nouvaeu like it was supposed to, additionally in bios there is no option (in the BIOS) for me to switch between the onboard intel graphics and my Nvidia card.

I need help, I did all the steps in that tutorial and the nouveau drivers are still the kernel modules.

Comment: Which nvidia graphics driver did you install (which number)? I think nvidiafb is the framebuffer tool (which is not the nvidia graphics driver). Please tell us more about the computer: Brand name and model. And edit your original question to add the output of `LANG=C sudo lshw -C display`. Indent each line of the output to render it as 'code'. This makes it easier to read (and to help you) :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your system is not finding any information about any Intel graphics. Maybe there is no such chip/card. Maybe there is such information, but you did not find it yet. Please check again, maybe with the help of `grep`.

My corresponding output from `lspci` in a Dell Precision M4800 is

```
$ lspci -k|grep -A4 VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
```

In order to add details, you can also check the output of `lshw`. My corresponding output is

```
$ LANG=C sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:f4000000-f4ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f5000000-f507ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:30 memory:f5400000-f57fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```